# Swift 3 - filter tableview from different view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have built an app that centers around a pretty tableview that I've built.

I have setup a secondary view controller as a menu that is presented modally, and I would like to filter the tableview by selecting one of the buttons on the secondary view controller.

For example, each cell has a City assigned to it. In the menu, I'd like to be able to click a city and filter the tableview to only show cells with that city.

I have too much code to paste, and I'm confident I can solve this problem with a smidge of direction.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: where is your problem? have you tried anything?

Comment: @Lu_ I've tried custom segues and such. I just can't get the tableview to filter or take any action from button clicks on the second view controller.

Comment: Don't show all your code, but please add _relevant_ code. Show us what you've tried, and what didn't work

Comment: make a delegate

Comment: It depends on how your tableView is set up, but you should use delegation. First please describe what are you already doing in your project. Step by step

Comment: Maybe try an unwind segue from your second view controller's buttons back to your table view controller?

Comment: @AshleyMills I hadn't thought of that. Can I call a filter function inside of that unwind?

Comment: @OlehZayats I tried delegation, but unsuccessfully. I'll give that another try.

Comment: @scttcrry you need to describe the steps or upload your project to github for example so that others can understand your problem. At this point I can advise only on very high level.

Comment: @OlehZayats I should have clarified. I am looking for high level. I can't share too much code because it's for a client in a tricky field. I just need a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with an unwind segue from your second view controller's buttons back to your table view controller.

In your table view controller, say,

```
func unwindToTableView(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    switch segue.identifier {
        case "FilterNames":
            filterByName()
        etc…
    }    
}
```

or you could have different unwind funcs for each filter…

```
func unwindAndFilterName(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    filterByName()
}

etc
```

To hook up an unwind segue, just add the method to your table view controller, then in your storyboard, drag from the button on the second view controller to it's **Exit** icon. The segue func should appear in the list

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what I was looking for! I'll give it a try!

Comment: This is what I ended up using! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

To do this you would like to have separate DataSource layer in the application to have move clear code.I will write small  example for you how it is possible to implement.

For example you have class `DataSource`. With information that you are showing. In my case it is `cities`. Now when I would like to do sorting I will call `sortAlphabetically()` and reload `tableview`. It is quite simple way and you're solution really depends on how you are working with `UITableView`.

```
class DataSource {

    var cities = ["Lviv", "Lutsk", "Kiev", "Rivne"]

    func sortAlphabetically() {
        cities = cities.sorted { $0 < $1 }
        //reload tableview hear
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try. Will this go in the tableviewcell.swift?

Comment: @scttcrry when you set delegates to the tableview. Do this self.tableview.datasource = DataSource

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do so is to use delegates, add a protocol to your filter view controller and a delegate function in tableView that filters datasource for tableView. Don't forget to assign your table view controller as the delegate before you segue to the filter viewcontroller

Best way to do so is to use delegates, add a protocol to your filter view controller and a delegate function in tableView that filters datasource for tableView. Don't forget to assign your table view controller as the delegate before you segue to the filter viewcontroller

Before your filterViewController

```
protocol FilterViewControllerDelegate {
    func tableViewCriteria(criteria: AnyObject)
}
```

In your filterViewController:

```
var delegate: FilterViewControllerDelegate?
```

In the class declaration of tableViewController, add FilterViewControllerDelegate

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController, FilterViewControllerDelegate{
```

Don't forget to set the FilterViewControllerDelegate to self before you segue to the filterView:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showFilter" {
            if let fvc = segue.destination as? FilterViewController{
                        fvc.delegate = self
            }
        }
}
```

Implement the func in tableView that will update tableView data source based on the chosen criteria:

```
//In myTableViewController
func tableViewCriteria(criteria: AnyObject) {
    //update tableView data source base on criteria here
     return
}
```

Finally, call the delegate function from filterView whenever you need to return to tableview:

```
self.delegate?.tableViewCriteria(criteria: foo)
```

Voila! :)